# Не пойму ошибку с присваиванием делегату метода C#

Tags: c#, массивы, делегаты

Сейчас знакомлюсь с делегатами на языке C#. *Задача состоит в том, что бы создать делегат, класс с символьным полем и методом присваивания значения полю. Затем создать массив объектов созданного класса и записать все свойства присвоения массива в один экземпляр делегата. Затем заполнить массив с помощью экземпляра.* Вроде всё сделал, но выдаёт ошибку : **"Делегат метода экземпляра не может иметь нулевым 'this'."** Не понимаю эту ошибку и прошу помочь с решением проблемы. Вот мой код:

```
delegate void MyDelegate(char symb);

    class Myclass
    {
        public char sym;

        public void Assign(char symb)
        {
            sym = symb;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Myclass[] array;
            Console.Write("Введите кол-во элементов массива:");
            array = new Myclass[Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())];
            MyDelegate meth = array[0].Assign;
            for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                meth += array[i].Assign;
            }
            meth('A');
            for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(array[i].sym + " | ");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: потому что у вас массив `array` состоит из null, там не никаких объектов

Comment: Всё,оказывается,было так просто, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
array = new Myclass[int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())];
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
    array[i] = new Myclass();
}
// ...
```